# Express Passport - warn and logout if user already logged in on another browser/computer?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Is it possible to check if a user is already logged in with the same username/email on another browser/computer in Passport.js and return a message that the user is already logged in, preventing multiple logins with the same user at the same time?

Or even check for "allowed" IP/MAC - addresses?

Comment: Yes it is, but you need to have a place where you store it ie. database which you query each time user logs in.

Comment: @ArturStary: OK, I use sessions and store in Mongodb. Able to give an example?